# How can I fix my twist pen that no longer extends the point?

Tags: pens

My twist pen was working just fine until I put it up to do something and came back to start again.  Now when I twist, it has no stop and the point won't come out.  There is no turning friction when I twist the pen.

I'm unaware of what brand it is and there is no visible problem with it. I can take off the very top, which holds the clip, and that's all.  It won't pull apart, and it isn't obvious how to access the inside, or the refill for replacement.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts. It sounds like the mechanism broke, but there isn't much information here to go on. What brand of pen is it? How much of it can you disassemble (and is there a visible cause when you do)? Does the inside look clean or is there something like dried ink binding the mechanism so something friction-fit is turning? Any chance you can take a snapshot of the disassembled pen?

Comment: Typically, twist pens pull apart in the middle to replace the refill.  What happens if you grab it at both ends and try pulling it apart?  Also, you say it now turns without the point coming out. Does it turn easily, with no significant friction, or does it have more resistance to turning than it did when it worked?

Comment: it wont pull apart and there is no friction when the pen twist

Comment: If there's no way to replace the refill, the mechanism may not have been designed to last, giving out before the refill. But let's see if any readers have ideas. One other thing to look at: see if either end unscrews (the top section that the clip cap goes into, or the conical tip that the point comes out of). The pen had to have been assembled somehow.

Comment: it unscrews in the middle but that's not happening. the top unscrews to reveal a round piece of metal with a black dot in the middle. it was designed to last the pen was made for a bug out bag and is made of heavy aluminum

Comment: So OP, what wound up happening?

Answer (score 3):

You have a mechanical pen of unknown origin that is broken. You report there is no way to open the pen to examine or adjust it. You say it just stopped working out of the blue. How to fix?

With the info you provided, the only fix is a new pen.

(Yes it *looks* rugged, maybe marketed as a **tactical pen** but no brand. Could be you got played by someone cashing in on the tactical pen niche.)

Comment: @user12998, unfortunately, I think this is the answer. The body may be sturdy aluminum or some other metal, but it sounds like the mechanism isn't.